# Lightest lock for exclusive inserts in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking, postgresql-9.6

I want to limit INSERTs to whichever transaction gets the lock (with the others waiting in line, not failing) while allowing concurrent reads, updates, and deletes (but obviously not of the data being inserted, which is impossible in PG anyway).

What is the lightest LOCK to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, a lock that prevents inserts also prevents updates en deletes. Maybe if you explain why you need this someone can supply a different solution.

Comment: I figured. I'm assuming SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE is my best choice?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just insert the data you need - any other transaction trying to insert the **same** primary key values will wait automatically. selects, updates and deletes on that table will still work.

Comment: I am manually manipulating the starting number in the sequence with each transaction. I have a specific sensible reason for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to lock a table against all concurrent modifications, `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` is the cheapest lock.

I'm not going to ask why you want to restrict concurrency in that way...